# Why do I measure a voltage between me and the hot wire?

Tags: voltage, current, ac, ground, multimeter

If I plug one lead of a multimeter to the outlet phase wire and the other lead to my hand, why does it show 100 V when I stand in carpet, and 150 V when I stand at pure floor? What causes that voltage?

Or if I measure voltage between hot wire and my PC that is not plugged to socket it shows 80 V. In my country we have 230 V AC.

Comment: Because of capacitance between you and Earth. Note that if you had inadvertently done this with the meter in current measurement mode you might not have been able to write this question (because you'd be dead). What you did is foolish.

Comment: ...also do not connect one lead of any voltmeter to mains, and the other to you.  That's just not a good idea, even if you do have faith in large multinational corporations.

Comment: You are one internal failure away from electrocution. Don’t do this.

Comment: If you still want to do such experiments, connect a 10÷20 kΩ resistor in series with the multimeter's probe.